# Selenium Webdriver Compound class names not permitted error

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to enter a value to a "id class" but im getting error

**"Compound class names not permitted"**

I have alreay tried cssSelector and i get **Unable to locate element**

Could you guys please help me?

[Example Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBoPS.jpg)

Here is my inital codes

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBoPS.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following options:

- `XPATH`:

  ```
  "//input[@name='From']"

  "//input[@class='txtText'][@name='From']"
  ```
- `CSS`:

  ```
  "input[name=From]"

  "input.txtText[name=From]"
  ```

Comment: Actually there are 4 options given, which both didn't work?

Comment: Sorry i meant both of xpath and css didn't work, it still gives the error "unable to locate element", i did class and cssselector searches for all of them and still gives me error

Comment: @E.Aksoy Great !!! we are closer to the solution now. Just add some `Explicit Wait` for the `element to be visible` for the element with the mentioned `xpath` or `css`, you will be successfully able to retrieve the text. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Airport or City']"));
```

Comment: my bad, first time asking a question :)

http://imgur.com/a/iMTEc

first one is my initial test method,

second one is the setmethod.

i would like to write "IST" in the class given at Example Website link

Comment: now i get invalid or illegal selection specified error, i tried to remove quotes and other stuff, but it didn't work

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Airport or City']")); this should work. Are you really trying with xpath or you tried with css?

Comment: Can you please share your code line where you are getting error?

Comment: `OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder='Airport or City']"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_` **i'm getting this error at**  `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@placeholder='Airport or City']")).SendKeys("IST");` **line**

Comment: Now you may need to troubleshoot it. Just try to get all the input elements and see if your element is there in list. Var elements=FindElements(By.XPath("//input"));

Comment: I had to put in a timeout, but thanks for your help :)